# Cross browser css issues (Safari vs Chrome)

Tags: css, safari

I am currently having issues with Safari not displaying background images and background colors in my css. Apparently its just the homepage.

```
#footer {
background-color: #00594c;
}

#home_widget_1 {
background-color: #00594c;
color: white;
height: 485px;
border-right: 1px solid white;
background-image: url(https://www.fvcolumbus.org/stage/wp-    content/uploads/2016/12/independent-living1.png);
background-size: 510px 282px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-right: 0px !important;
background-position: center top;
}

#home-featured-image {
height: 540px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
max-width: 1280px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-image: url(../stage/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/10192016_homepage.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please provide all information regarding your question in the question text. No one with a brain between their ears is going to click on your custom link, hopefully, which could be an attack vector.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had caching issues.